# DateTimeFormatter dd MMM yyyy prints period after month (01 Apr. 2023)

Tags: java, java-time, date-formatting, datetimeformatter

When I run below code in the server, I get period after month.

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy").format(LocalDate.parse("2023-04-01"))

01 Apr. 2023
```

There is a period after month.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi6xu.png)

But, same code when I run in java main method, it produces expected output.

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy").format(LocalDate.parse("2023-04-01"))

01 Apr 2023
```

Any reason why the first operation produces period?

Is dateTimeFormatter depends on Locale?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: You are correct, it is a locale difference. Perhaps `Apr.` with a dot is German or something and `Apr` without the dot is English or something else. Specify the locale you want, for example `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)`.

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Comment: @BasilBourque  This is related to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8211750 .

Answer (score 1):

Its depends on Locale.

it produces correct results when I use Locale.US

LocalDate.parse("2023-01-01").format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.US))